# How to make Netlogo multiplayer?

Tags: netlogo

Can anyone point me towards resources to learn how to make multi-player simulations, with messages being passed between multiple computers?

Answer (score 2):

From https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/hubnet.html:

> HubNet is a technology that lets you use NetLogo to run participatory simulations in the classroom. In a participatory simulation, a whole class takes part in enacting the behavior of a system as each student controls a part of the system by using an individual device, such as a networked computer [...].

It doesn't have to be students in a classroom. HubNet allows you to build general multi-player simulations in NetLogo.

The link above will give you a general introduction to HubNet. For more in debt information, check out the [HubNet Authoring Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/hubnet-authoring.html).